# Setting timeouts with supertest not working

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm trying to test my server with some code like so:

```
describe 'POST /do/some/stuff/', ->
  it 'should do this thing', (done) ->
    request app
      .post '/do/some/stuff/'
      .timeout 10000
      .expect 200
      .end (err, res) ->
        return done err if err?
        done()
```

The thing that the server is doing usually takes a few seconds, which is longer than the default timeout of 2000ms, so I call `.timeout 10000`. However, despite this, when I run the code I get:

```
1) POST /do/some/stuff/ should do this thing:
   Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
```

What do I need to do to increase this timeout?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing the timeout on your `request` object does not change anything to Mocha's default timeout. Doing `this.timeout(10000)` (whatever the CoffeeScript equivalent is) inside your test should take care of that.

Comment: doesn't work for me, I have like a 20 second wait for a query call and it still jumps right to my assert before it can return.

Comment: @WeDoTDD If it does not work for you that's because there's *another problem with your code*. You should ask another question. Downvoting an answer that actually *does* work amounts to doing harm to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the timeout when running your test framework. For instance for mocha it would be like `mocha -t 7000` . Alternatively, you can add a test with setTimeout just to create a delay (if the required delay is in between tests).